# Chrome Third party Phaseout

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, third-party-cookies

I have several questions on this, we were doing audit of third party cookies, there were some cookies that were blocked when disabled third party cookies and our system still works fine. When checking psat tool it showed that functionality as broken. Do we need to consider result of psat and issues even if our functionality is working fine

I am expecting solution for this question

Comment: Not all browsers are immediately affected, see the [timeline](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/prepare/prepare-for-phaseout).

Comment: "*I am expecting solution for this question*" - this is something you should refrain from including in your questions; the assumption is that (aside from spam or other inappropriate questions) people are always looking for assistance. That said: you've provided no details, only a general question. Please read [ask].